# In NetBeans, is it possible to reattach .form and .java files?

Tags: netbeans6.7

Somehow, my `.form` files and `.java` files for my GUIs built with the NetBeans GUI editor became detached and now appear in my project as two separate files. I'm not sure why this happened or how to correct it, but until it is corrected, I am not able to use the GUI editor to edit the files.

I've already tried closing and reopening the project, but that did not work. I also tried deleting the project (but not the source files) and reimporting it, and that too did not work.

Has this happened to anyone else? What could cause this (so I can avoid it in the future) and what can I do to correct this problem?

Comment: I'm curious as to why this was downvoted...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what caused this problem, but I was able to fix it by closing the project, closing NetBeans, deleting all of the NetBeans project files, and then reimporting the code as a project. It appears everything is back to the way it was.